# how to view multiple checkbox values from database in codeigniter in different forms with single table

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tell me that how to view multiple checkbox values from database in codeigniter in different forms with single table.
This is my code that I have done yet. please help me

this is the error shows

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php

Line Number: 683

Backtrace:

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\homestaynew\web\application\models\Main_Model.php
Line: 165
Function: where

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\homestaynew\web\application\controllers\Main.php
Line: 929
Function: updateData2

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\homestaynew\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '134 = '' WHERE `id` = `Array`' at line 1

UPDATE `hostmain` SET 134 = '' WHERE `id` = `Array`

Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/homestaynew/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

**view**

```
    <?php foreach ($result as $key => $row) {?>

     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $row['id'] ?>"> 

        <input type="hidden" name="propertytype" value="<?= $row['propertytype'] ?>">



    <input type="hidden" name="guesthave" value="<?= $row['guesthave']  ?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="guestaccomodate" value="<?= $row['guestaccomodate'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="bedroomuse1" value="<?= $row['bedroomuse1'] ?>">

     <input type="hidden" name="guestbedroom" value="<?= $row['guestbedroom'] ?>">
     <input type="hidden" name="guest1" value="<?= $row['guest1'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="guest2" value="<?= $row['guest2'] ?>">
     <input type="hidden" name="guest3" value="<?= $row['guest3'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="guest4" value="<?= $row['guest4'] ?>">
     <input type="hidden" name="bedroomuse2" value="<?= $row['bedroomuse2'] ?>">
     <input type="hidden" name="guest5" value="<?= $row['guest5'] ?>">
     <input type="hidden" name="guest6" value="<?= $row['guest6'] ?>">

         <input type="hidden" name="guest7" value="<?= $row['guest7'] ?>">
     <input type="hidden" name="guest8" value="<?= $row['guest8'] ?>">
     <input type="hidden" name="bedroomuse3" value="<?= $row['bedroomuse3'] ?>">

   <input type="hidden" name="bathroom_accomodate[]" value="<?= $row['bathroom_accomodate'] ?>" >

      <input type="hidden" name="bathroomused" value="<?= $row['bathroomused'] ?>">

      <input type="hidden" name="location" value="<?= $row['location'] ?>">

      <input type="hidden" name="amenities[]"  value="<?= $row['amenities']  ?>">
         <input type="hidden" name="sharedspaces[]"  value="<?= $row['sharedspaces'] ?>">
  <?php  } ?>
```

**controller**

```
  $bathroom_accomodate =implode(',',$this->input->post('bathroom_accomodate'));
        $bathroomused = $this->input->post('bathroomused');

        $location=$this->input->post('location');
        $amenities=implode(',',$this->input->post('amenities'));
        $sharedspaces=implode(',',$this->input->post('sharedspaces'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$components = array(array('component_key' => 'address'),array('component_key' => 'education'));

$client_details = array('address' => 1);

foreach ($components as $key => $value)
{

  $data = array('name'          => 'components[]',
                'value'         => $value['component_key'],
                'checked'       => ($client_details[$value['component_key']] == 1) ? TRUE : FALSE
            );
  echo "<div class='col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-4 form-group'><div class='checkbox'><label>";
  echo form_checkbox($data).$value['component_key'];
  echo "</label></div></div>";
  echo "<div class='clearfix'></div>";
}
```